# Fetch Jenkins information from a website

Tags: javascript, php, jenkins

I am building a website where I want to display specific information from an open Jenkins server. How can I do that from my PHP or JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XML API or the JSON API of Jenkins.
Simply type:

> **/api/xml**

or

> **/api/json**

to the end of the URL you would type in the browser to see the info you need from Jenkins and you will get the result in that format. And you can parse that result from your script.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually handy, but didn't solve what i need. Let's say I want to fetch the current build/job running on this server:
https://build.opnfv.org/ci/computer/lf-pod2/builds . How to get the Build Executor Status?

Comment: @hosselausso As mentioned on https://build.opnfv.org/ci/api/ _Build queue has its own separate API_: https://build.opnfv.org/ci/queue/api/

Comment: I found a way to get all the current running jobs using the tree query.

https://build.opnfv.org/ci/computer/api/xml?tree=computer[executors[currentExecutable[url]],oneOffExecutors[currentExecutable[url]]]&xpath=//url&wrapper=builds

Next step is to get the running job given a slave name... The documentation about this is very poor..

Comment: Some progress. 
https://build.opnfv.org/ci/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,lastBuild[*]]

This shows all the jobs. Now I have to filter by <building>true</building> and I can get the slave name from <builtOn> tag

Any ideas how to filter that in the url query?

Comment: Why filter? You're already loading the response to your java script? just filter it there. 
I would use : /api/json?pretty=true&depth=2&tree=builds[builtOn,building]

Comment: I used xpath in the end. Something like this. 
https://build.opnfv.org/ci/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,lastBuild[*]]&xpath=hudson/job[lastBuild/building=%22true%22]&wrapper=hudson

Answer (score 0):

Use : /api/json?pretty=true&depth=2&tree=builds[builtOn,building]

Load this to your script and parse the results.

Good luck.